# Finding a line making an angle θ with a known line

Tags: math, geometry

I have a line from (*a*, *b*) to (*x*, *y*), and I would like to draw a line starting at (*x*, *y*), with length ℓ, that makes an angle of θ with the original line.

How do I compute the coordinates of the endpoint of this new line? See the diagram:

[image]

Comment: Can you work out the angle between your first line and the y axis? If you did know it, would you be able to work out the unknown coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nearly always simpler to use vector algebra for this kind of thing, rather than Cartesian coordinates. Let's start by labelling the points:

[image]

Let R(θ) be the matrix that rotates by θ radians *counter-clockwise*:

[image]

Then compute:

**v** = **B** − **A** (the vector from **A** to **B**)

**v̂** = **v** / |**v**| (the unit vector in the direction of **v**)

**ŵ** = R(−θ) **v̂** (the unit vector in the direction of **BC**; your rotation is *clockwise*, so we need R(−θ) here, not R(θ))

**w** = ℓ **ŵ** (the vector of length ℓ in the direction of **BC**)

**C** = **B** + **w**

This approach avoids the need to compute an arctangent, which would need some care (if done naïvely, it runs into trouble when **B** is vertically above or below **A**; but most languages have a function like `atan2` for handling this case).

In any sensible programming language with a vector library you should be able to write this as a one-liner, perhaps like this:

```
C = B + (B - A).unit().rotate(-theta) * l
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, so after a lot of scribbling, I came up with this:

[image]

The dashed lines represent lines parallel to the x- and y-axes.

m = x − a

n = y − b

α = tan<sup>−1</sup> (n / m)

β = α − θ

p = ℓ cos β

q = ℓ sin β

c = x + p

d = y + q

Comment: Thanks for the edit. What did you use to create the graphic? Thanks